# scroll to top using href id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to scroll the div to top position.I have problem with get the href value.now 'a' returns undefined in `console.log(a);`

```js
function myFunction()
    {
       var a=$(this).attr('href');
    console.log(a);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+a).offset().top-40}, 500);
 }
```

```css
#consulting,#segments,#partner,#insights{min-height:100vh;}
   .secMenu{position:fixed;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row secMenu">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 menu">
   <ul class="nav navMenu">
   
     <li class="test1"><a href="#consulting" onclick="myFunction()">Consulting & Solutions</a></li>
     <li class="test2"><a href="#segments"  onclick="myFunction()">Segments</a></li>
     <li class="test3"><a href="#partner"  onclick="myFunction()">Our Partners</a></li>
     <li class="test4"><a href="#insights"  onclick="myFunction()">Perspectives</a></li>
   </ul>  
  </div>
  
    </div>   <!--End of second menu -->
     <div class="row">
    <div id="consulting">
    div1
  </div>
  <div id="segments">
  div11
  </div>
  <div id="partner">
  div111
  </div>
  <div id="insights">
   div1111
  </div>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Why is `$(document).ready` inside myFunction?

Comment: and `$(this).attr('href')` inside `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: There are many syntax and other errors in your code...

Comment: kindly check my snippet now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made an alternative to what you used, but it does the same thing. I removed the function you used and used jQuery instead. Hope my answer works for you:

```js
$('.nav li a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(a).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
#consulting,
#segments,
#partner,
#insights {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.secMenu {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row secMenu">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 menu">
      <ul class="nav navMenu">

        <li class="test1"><a href="#consulting">Consulting & Solutions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="test2"><a href="#segments">Segments</a>
        </li>
        <li class="test3"><a href="#partner">Our Partners</a>
        </li>
        <li class="test4"><a href="#insights">Perspectives</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--End of second menu -->
  <div class="row">
    <div id="consulting">
      div1
    </div>
    <div id="segments">
      div11
    </div>
    <div id="partner">
      div111
    </div>
    <div id="insights">
      div1111
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To see it in action you can hit the Run code snippet button above or you can see a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9amg24un/).

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` is bind to the global object by default (in browser it's `window`).

You can try pass `this` to `myFunction()` like this: `myFunction(this)`. And in `myFunction` definition: `function myFunction(target) {...}`, `target` now refers to the anchor element.